# EXT JS 4: No reloading of stores

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-stores

I have a `TreeStore`, which initially loads its data from a json file with success:

```
Ext.define('MM.store.InventoryTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires: 'MM.model.InventoryTree',
    model:'MM.model.InventoryTree',       
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read : 'json/inventorytree.json'
        },
        root: {
            text: 'Countries',
            expanded: true
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried several things, and the following function makes sense to me, but something stops it from actually reloading.

```
onReloadButtonClick: function(){                
        var store = Ext.getCmp('InventoryTree').getView().getStore();
        store.removeAll(); // this works!
        store.reload(); // this is executed, but nothing happened (no network traffic)
}
```

Maybe it loads its data, but the view prevents it from showing up? What could I be missing?

Comment: let us see the server response body please

Comment: If you mean the ajax call: there is no respone, because there is no request.

Answer (score 0):

It might be ExtJS that is missing:  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-reload

> It looks like this [reload] method was taken out in 4.1.0 but is back in 4.1.1

Are you using 4.1.1?

Are you positive that reload is executing?  If you put an alert after the reload line does it get shown?

Comment: If you are using 4.1.0 it seems you can just use load - reload simply passes the original load options to load

Comment: You can just use `load()`, but be aware that you might have to call `getRootNode().removeAll()` before: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151211-Reloading-TreeStore-adds-all-records-to-store-getRemovedRecords&p=674231&viewfull=1#post674231

Comment: that´s not the problem. reload is currently a synonymous for load.

Comment: anyway, the easy fix is to go to 4.1.1 - and hope that new bugs creep in only on .0 releases.  :)

Comment: I have extended the store by the beforeload-listener, which  calls `this.getRootNode().removeAll()`. This works initially, but not when called by `store.load()`.

Comment: have you confirmed that the reload method is actually there (breakpoint and/or alert message after)  and not throwing an exception?  if it is not there, make sure you've cleared all caches and are using the new JS.

Comment: I can confirm everything. I even debugged into `load()` function but it has so much overhaed, that it's nothing for me yet.

Comment: hmm - yeah, going into the bowels of extjs is never fun.  is there any chance your data might be somehow corrupted?  and you are using ext-all-debug.js?